# R extract matching values from list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a relatively large amount of data stored in a list of data frames with several columns.
For each element of the list I wish to check one column against a reference and if present extract the value held in another column of the same element and place in a new summary matrix.

e.g. with the following example code:

```
add1 = c("N1","N1","N1")
coords1 = c(1,2,3)
vals1 = c("a","b","c")
extra1 = c("x","y","x")

add2 = c("N2","N2","N2","N2")
coords2 = c(2,3,4,5)
vals2 = c("b","c","d","e")
extra2 = c("z","y","x","x")

add3 = c("N3","N3","N3")
coords3 = c(1,3,5)
vals3 = c("a","c","e")
extra3 = c("z","z","x")

df1 <- data.frame(add1, coords1, vals1, extra1)
df2 <- data.frame(add2, coords2, vals2, extra2)
df3 <- data.frame(add3, coords3, vals3, extra3)

list_all <- list(df1, df2, df3)

coordinate.extract <- unique(unlist(lapply(list_all, "[", 1)))

my_matrix <- matrix(0, ncol = length(list_all)
              , nrow = (length(coordinate.extract)))

my_matrix_new <- cbind(as.character(coordinate.extract)
                       , my_matrix)
```

I would like to end up with:

```
my_matrix_new = V1 V2 V3 V4
                 1  a     a
                 2  b  b
                 3  c  c  c
                 4     d
                 5     e  e
```

i.e. the 3rd column of each list element is chosen based on the value of the second column.

I hope this is clear.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `data.frame` as there are mixed classes.  You may try `merge` with `Reduce` to get the expected output.  Select the 2nd and 3rd columns,in each `list` element, change the column name for the 2nd to be same across all the list elements, `merge`, and if needed replace the `NA` elements with `''`

```
lst1 <- lapply(list_all, function(x) {names(x)[2] <- 'V1';x[2:3] })
res <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='V1', all=TRUE), lst1)
res[-1] <- lapply(res[-1], as.character)
res[is.na(res)] <- ''
res
#  V1 vals1 vals2 vals3
#1  1     a           a
#2  2     b     b      
#3  3     c     c     c
#4  4           d      
#5  5           e     e
```

We can change the column names

```
names(res) <- paste0('V', seq_along(res))
```

Comment: Although it worked on the original example it didn’t work on my actual data which had more than two columns. I have edited the question to try and make this clearer.

Comment: @mattbawn If there are more than 2 columns, from the expected output, it seems that you are using only the first 2 columns?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I have edited the example coed to give more complex data frames (i.e. with extra "undesirable" columns) but my expected output still remains what I am hoping to obtain.

Comment: @mattbawn Just change `lst1 <- lapply(list_all, function(x) {names(x)[1] <- 'V1'; x[1:2]})` and it should get the expected result

Comment: I am trying to get it to work with my data. I have 5 columns in each list element and I want the output to reflect the value of only the 3rd column based on the value of the second. However the output I get at the moment contains all 5 columns.

Comment: @mattbawn In that case, you need to subset the 2nd and 3rd column instead of 1st and 2nd I showed. i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(list_all, function(x) {names(x)[2] <- 'V1'; x[2:3]})`